# How to enable Cross scripting in Apache?

Tags: apache

I want to enable cross scripting in Apache. I am using AngularJS. I tried everything in AngularJs side. I can't do it. Is there a way to enable in apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add following line to .htaccess

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

If you want to allow some specific site. refer the below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options